# How to 'defaultProps' when some fields are required?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a scenario where I want to set `defaultProps` for an optional prop:

```
interface IAppProps {
  requiredProp : string; //should always be passed into component
  optionalProp?: string;
}

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, {}>{
    public static defaultProps: IAppProps = {
        optionalProp: 'set from defaultProps!'
    };

    public render(){
      return <div>{this.props.requiredProp} - {this.props.optionalProp}</div>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App requiredProp="Hello world" />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

However, this throws and error because when I create `defaultProps`, it does not contain `requiredProp`:

> Type '{ optionalProp: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IAppProps'.
>     Property 'requiredProp' is missing in type '{ optionalProp: string; }'

What is the standard way of doing this?  Do i just pass `null` or `undefined` into the required prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd split them, like that

```
interface interface IAppOptionalProps {
  optionalProp?: string;
}

interface IAppProps extends IAppOptionalProps {
  requiredProp: string;
}
```

and then let your `defaultProps` be of type `IAppOptionalProps`

```
public static defaultProps: IAppOptionalProps = {
  optionalProp: 'set from defaultProps!'
};
```

When you think about it, your `defaultProps` are not `IAppProps` and shouldn't be of such type, they're rather of type `IAppOptionalProps` as defined above.

Comment: nice! why didn't I think of that ;)